# Site design: 404/captcha/error page images

Tags: discussion, design

I'm getting close to converting the new design to css and ready for site graduation and launch soon! Meanwhile, I need some ideas for the [error](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/error), [captcha](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/captcha) and [404](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/404) page images. They should be light-hearted and relate to Christianity.

For the captcha image, I normally use a non-human figure. (it asks "Are you human?")

Please post your ideas here, preferably with photo/image references.

**A few examples for other SE sites:**

[image: Travel.se captcha]

Travel.se captcha

[image: English.se captcha]

English.se captcha

[image: Travel.se 404]

Travel.se 404

[image: Bicycles.se error]

Bicycles.se error

Answer (score 20):

I'm sorry, how can you have a 404 and *not* have some reference to "He is not here! He is risen!"

[image]

Comment: Yes, this idea for the 404 is perfect.

Comment: Love it! Do you know if we can use this exact image? If it's creative commons, I can add the artist name/url to it.

Comment: This was justa  google search image.  I found it at: http://www.google.com/imgres?sa=X&biw=1112&bih=574&tbm=isch&tbnid=gQ6ui2Q0NZ5_LM:&imgrefurl=http://www.layministryfumc.com/BillsSundayMessage/tabid/77/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/119/The-Empty-Tomb.aspx&docid=ToO9s3m_cGn75M&imgurl=http://www.layministryfumc.com/Portals/0/The%252520Empty%252520Tomb.jpg&w=350&h=343&ei=OlCeUa22HM2g4APVwYDoBQ&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:38,s:0,i:286

Comment: after some reverse image look up, I found the artist is [Frank P. Ordaz](http://ordazart.com/workszoom/436905) I'll attribute the image to him.

Answer (score 15):

Some ideas for captcha:

[Matthew 7:15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew%207:15&version=NIV) themed:

[image]

Broad and narrow path - doesn't include non-humans, but distinguishing is definitely there:

[image]

Comment: Wolf in sheep's clothing for captcha seems just about perfect.

Answer (score 8):

## For the captcha

If you want animals pretending to be human - Medieval Christianity was very fond of illustrating animals in human situations. There's no shortage of various creatures dressed up, hunting, besieging one another, etc. Of course we also want to have a Christian theme. The following are from devotional books.

(1.) From a [book of hours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_hours) of 1460 (Museum Meermanno-Westreenianum, Den Haag, MS 10F50, f. 6r) comes this fox-monk trying to decipher some writing ([source](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fuchs.margin_(MMW10F50_f6r)_detail.jpg)):

[image: Fox reading]

(2.) Another Dutch book of hours ([British Library, MS Stowe 17, f. 84](http://www.bl.uk/catalogues/illuminatedmanuscripts/ILLUMIN.ASP?Size=mid&IllID=410)) has a fox, disguised as a priest, preaching something probably-dubious to some poultry:

[image: Fox preaching]

It's a popular theme (related to Matthew 7:15, and often used in polemics against false preachers) but I like this one in particular because of their facial expressions.

Both of these images are public domain.

Comment: I really like the first for a CAPTCHA.  I like the second, but I don't know if it would work for one of the other pages.  It would be really awesome for the whole site to be designed around the idea of an illustrated manuscript!

Answer (score 7):

### CAPTCHA

> It is easier for a camel to go through the eye of a needle...
>   (Mark 10:25a [ESV](http://legacy.esvbible.org/Mark+10/))

[image: LEGO camel.]

### Error

> Do not throw your pearls before pigs. (Matthew 7:6b [ESV](http://legacy.esvbible.org/Matthew+7/))

[image: No pearls before swine]

### 404

> Do not lay up for yourselves treasures on earth, where moth and rust destroy and where thieves break in and steal, but lay up for yourselves treasures in heaven, where neither moth nor rust destroys and where thieves do not break in and steal. (Matthew 6:19-20 [ESV](http://legacy.esvbible.org/Matthew+6/))

[image: Moth eaten mink]

Comment: The last one is tough to find images of that make sense...

Comment: +1'd for the first two. The last one...yeah, I'm not sure it works all that well.

Comment: I like the error one. Pearls before swine

Comment: Man... That second one would be perfect if we still had a custom message for the "moderator deleted your question" 404... Whose bright idea was it to let folks see their deleted posts, anyway?!

Answer (score 3):

## An error image

[image: oops]

An infamous fresco restoration gone a bit awry. I think it is fairly recognizable and matches the concept. On the negative side: perhaps it is a bit cruel to the artist? Also, I read that she has been asking for royalties, though I don't know what the actual legal situation might be.

Comment: I find this humours personally, but I'm afraid some people may get offended by it? After all, it was a great loss.

Comment: They called it [the monkey boy of Borja](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+monkey+boy+of+&oq=the+monkey+boy+of+&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3.11277j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#gs_rn=12&gs_ri=psy-ab&pq=the%20monkey%20boy%20painting&cp=23&gs_id=15&xhr=t&q=the%20monkey%20boy%20of%20Borja&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=the+monkey+boy+of+Borja&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.eWU&fp=bafd714da88029de&biw=1366&bih=667). I laughed pretty hard when I read about this story.

Comment: Royalties? For a botched restoration work turned meme? I'm in the wrong line of work.

Answer (score 2):

For the Captcha, the story of [Balaam's ass](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers+22&version=NIV) comes to mind.  In the story, Balaam is off to help the enemies of the children of Israel, and so God sets an Angel to kill him. Balaam's donkey sees the angel, and keeps trying to protect Balaam, but Balaam is beating him to get him to move forward.  Finally, God gives the donkey the power of speech in order to warn Balaam of what is going on...

[image]

I got it here: http://gc2012.spokanediocese.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/balaams_donkey1.jpg

I'm assuming its public domain, only because of the age.

Answer (score 1):

## I like this for the error:

[image]

## And this for the captcha

[image]

or the full one

[image]

Comment: +1 for error image; I am not really fond of "The Creation of Adam" (it's not Calvinistic! :-\) and it does not fit the "non-human figure" aspect (not that such is *critical*).

Answer (score 1):

I could not find an image with a very quick Google search, but I wonder if it would be appropriate to use for the Captcha image a scene depicting the guarding of the Jordan in Judges 12 where "shibboleth" was used to determine if someone truly was not an Ephraimite.  Such does not present a "non-human figure", but it would carry the concept of separation.

(Along similar lines, something with the sheep and the goats from Matthew 25:31+ might not be inappropriate, though such might feel harsh--not that slaughtering Ephraimites is light-hearted but at least that was only temporal judgment.)